# Get UPN by SAM account name outside domain?

Tags: active-directory, registry, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am workimg on a legacy application where users login in with there SAM account name DOMAIN/USERNAME. We moved some of our auth to azure ad which requires the UPN EMAIL@DOMAIN.COM. We don't want to change the user experience but we cannot find a way to translate the SAM account name to the UPN outside the domain.

Any suggestions? Graph Api, registry hack?

Microsoft Graph API looked like a possibility but does not support filtering on [onPremisesSamAccountName](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user).

Comment: You could try to use the regular expression to translate the format in Azure AD Connect.

Comment: If you check the MS Graph change log here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog, you can see they added `onPremisesSamAccountName` to the User entity a while ago. While I'm not sure if you can filter on this property, it should at least make it possible to find the corresponding Azure AD UPN.

Comment: `onPremisesImmutableId` supports $filter, so if you can figure out that you can find the user with a single query.